# Chainmail's making a comeback

Tags: internal-consistency, society, armors

In a society that is the same as ours in every way imaginable, how can I make chainmail fashionable? I want children to get really angry because mom won't buy the newest titanium chainmail. At your friend's wedding? Say goodbye to that tux; meet the new chainmail suit. How can I make a coat of chainmail the Christmas gift everyone wants?

Comment: Mail by itself is insufficient protection, you would need as a minimum a quilted gambeson under the mail to spread impact forces from a sword blow. Read how fighting men were dressed and equipped from Roman times (yes, the Legions were equipped with mail armour, the *lorica segmentata* we associate with Legions never fully supplemented or replaced mail armour) to @ 1200, when mail began to be supplemented and then replaced by plate armour.

Comment: The best way to make everyone want it? Tell them they can't have it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Real chain-mail is tear-resistant (translated; stab-resistant), and with the advent of modern alloys, it's possible for it to be bullet-resistant. About 10 years back in Britain, just after the handgun ban there, school students and skinheads alike developed this twisted social custom of stabbing each other as discretely as possible while in passing, leading garment designers to offer a like of Kevlar-layered stab-resistant school uniforms that became a vogue. Kevlar's pretty ugly though, and it works in school uniforms mainly because the fashion is a fairly thick coat and trousers anyway. In a United States (frankly a world) where distrust of law enforcement and your own neighbors is at highs not seen since Reconstruction, something with the striking look of chainmail, that obviously provides protection from personal weapons, might be practical enough to make its own fashion statement.
- Not everyone can wear a real shirt of chain mail. A shirt with enough coverage and ring strength to actually be useful protection would weigh about 50-70 pounds depending on the size of the wearer and the material (lighter metals that provided similar protection, such as titanium, would be more expensive). This wouldn't just be a fashion statement, it would speak at length about your physical strength and stamina.
- Mail has several qualities making it perfectly suited for women's designer fashions. The material is historically something men wore, so a woman wearing a traditionally male garment tailored to fit her form is all the more feminine. Mail also has that not-quite-nothing quality that lace is prized for to create nude illusions, making the garment seem more revealing than it really is. For a pure chainmail garment that could be no illusion, especially in thinner patterns and larger ring sizes, but with a flesh-tone leotard underneath it would give that head-turning "is she really nude under that" look that high fashion often leans on.
- Nobody can really predict fashion trends. Designers have played around with the material on and off for decades, and it's really only a matter of time before these fashion concepts catch on more widely than the Hollywood red carpets:

  [image]

All that said, it has several downsides as an everyday clothing material:

- Chainmail is fairly expensive from a square-foot perspective. Some of the fastest machines that make chain mail only do 260 rings per minute; for thicker patterns like one-into-8, 260 rings isn't even a square foot, and it might take 2 or even 3 square yards to make a full-length women's dress. It's even more expensive to pay someone a living wage to make the stuff by hand.
- Real stuff is heavy, lightweight stuff is delicate, and trying to make it both durable and light with alternate metals makes it even more expensive.
- Most mail patterns are see-through at some if not most angles, especially in ring sizes small enough to not look like a renaissance-fair reject. Wearing it as the only garment would only be tolerated in cultures with more relaxed attitudes toward nudity.
- Mail constantly grabs and pulls on body hair. People who wore it as armor typically started with a thick quilted turtleneck undershirt for a bit of padding as well as to prevent being slowly plucked from neck to foot. A full body shavedown or wax would be an alternate option (and many people, men and women, already subject themselves to this) but head hair would either have to be short or well-restrained.
- Mail has effectively zero insulating or windbreaking capacity. Thus an undergarment of some sort becomes even more of a necessity if the temperature's not in that 70-80* butter zone.
- An unbroken pattern of mail only folds in very specific directions and only to a certain degree, depending on pattern and ring size; more often than not, the best storage for chain mail is on a mannequin.
- The mail will abrade anything softer that it comes in contact with, like cloth cushions, wooden furniture, painted drywall, etc.
- Rust can be a problem even with modern stainless alloys. Don't count on the long-term durability of chain being a selling point.
- It is impossible to move silently in real chainmail without looking like you're trying to sneak around in broad daylight. Not great when you need to get to the bathroom at church during a pastor's sermon.

Comment: Chain mail made of steel, etc. is heavy. Chainmail of kevlar, not so much. Then again, Kevlar protection does not benefit from chainmail construction nearly as much as chainmail benefits steel armor construction. You mention Kevlar of course, don't want to steal your question. Maybe you feel like discussing the Kevlar alternative in more detail. +1

Comment: Kevlar is strong in tension, and would not work as chain mail. Kevlar vests are closely woven layers of the fibre, with multiple layers to provide the energy absorption to stop bullet strikes.

Comment: 50-70 pounds is way too much. I have a two chainmails at home (3/4 round ring haubergeon, and a long arm flat ring hauberk): both way around 16 kg which is around 35 lbs.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that you can't.  There's no need for people to have chainmail and consider it fashionable, when there is no significant need for its protection.  You'd have to change something *else* first.

The longer answer is that you *can* make chainmail fashionable if you change something *else* so that it *is* necessary.

The most logical reason why a society might want to wear chainmail - *and* make it a fashion item - is if the laws outlawing all forms of duelling had never been passed, if it was perfectly legal to kill someone with a cutting implement.

If we have a society where duels may be very impromptu and are fought with slashing swords or knives, where the duels are fought for the most part (by tradition and/or law) to the first touch, regardless of injury or death or lack thereof to the combatants, then chainmail would be a vital fashion accessory.

Of course, you'd have to have laws or traditions that would penalise anyone inflicting a narrow penetrating trauma, such as a stab wound or bullet wound, otherwise you'd end up with plate armour, not chainmail.

In such an environment, if you *weren't* wearing your chainmail, you might be severely injured or killed in one of the frequent duels, whereas *with* chainmail, you might take a hit, and honour would be satisfied, and you could walk away.

If duels are that common, you wouldn't want to be wearing easily damaged cloth except in a place where a duel was unlikely, or beneath your mail, or unless you were rich enough to be able to afford to replace it frequently.  Since such places where cloth would be practical would mostly be in one's own home, wearing cloth as an outer garment could pick up an erotic connotation.

So, if chainmail outer wear is the sensible option for most people, it is highly likely in an industrialised society similar to ours that it could be produced in large quantities quite cheaply for the most part, from pretty much any metal.

Aluminium would have the advantage of cheapness, lightness and ability to be anodised, as would Magnesium, though they wouldn't be all that strong.  Titanium would be strong, and lighter than steel.  Steel and Titanium could be plated, and Titanium can also be anodised.  Copper, brass and gold might be used for their colours.

It would also be relatively simple to mix ring materials, colours and sizes to produce complicated designs.  Have a look at http://www.mailleartisans.org.

Comment: _The short answer is that you can't. There's no need for people to have chainmail and consider it fashionable, when there is no significant need for its protection. You'd have to change something else first._ I have a chainmail and I think it's fashionable. At least, it's more fashionable than todays clothes you get at the "normal" shops. Also a chainmail is far not enough protection for a sword blow. You would end with broken bones. You need at least an additional thick undergarment which could be really unpleasent in summer.

Comment: @Bounce, as a fashion item, chainmail - save as small items of jewellery - is rather impractical.  Sure it may become fashionable at some point, but without a clear need, due to its weight and expense, is all too likely to drop back out of fashion quite quickly.  I rather like chainmail too, but the two of us liking it hardly makes it mainstream fashion. Besides, if the duelling swords are very light - which seems probable, since they are weight that has to be carried, and a lighter sword is faster - then padding could be kept to a minimum.

Comment: Sure, I got your point. That was more jokingly ;). About the weight: A standard longsword weighs about 1 - 2 kg, a tourney sword (which has a thinner, more bendable blade) weighs about 1 kg. At tourneys you have to wear effectiv padding armor and still sometimes there are injuries like a broken finger or even a fyling tooth ^^.